# Is there a way to use infinite scroll loader in client-side row model?

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

In my application, we are using the **'Client-Side'** row model in more than 50 tables. 
Now more data is coming from back-end, so loading all the data at a time in table gives performance issue.

I knew, I should use 'Infinite/Server side' row model. But replacing for all the tables takes more time.
So I am loading data by calling API when vertical scroll reach bottom of the grid by using 'onBodyScroll' event.

Here, I don't want to use 'showLoadingOverlay' to display loader while fetching the data from back-end.
Because it freeze the whole grid while displaying loader. It doesn't look user friendly. I want to use loader like 'Infinite' row model. Display the loader on last rows in grid, So user could see the other data while fetching data from back-end is in process.

How to achieve this in 'Client Side' row model?

**AG-GRID - VERSION: 23.0.3**

Please help me.
Thanks.

Comment: client side row model simply means all data are available at client side. So if you want to load the data from server, either (1) use infinite row model (invest your time) `OR` (2) append  new data to the existing `rowData`; after getting new data with your approach - instead of showing loading overlay, indicate the user regarding the info for background data load with some smart usability indicator

Comment: for more help, share your code, reproduce your issue/situation with plunk/stackblitz so that others can help u easily